# Multithreading C++ literature for Beginners

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to learn Multithreading in C++ and I'm therefore on the hunt for some good literature on the subject containing lots of code and examples. I've found several books online but I was hoping that someone could give a tip on books that you've read yourself and found beneficial for your learning.

Thanks in advance for any reply on the subject

Comment: There are various things. Check out Posix threads: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/  and OpenMP: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/ Two different approaches suited for almost all needs :)

Comment: c++11 http://www.manning.com/williams/ + there are also good videos from conferences, check youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about concurrency and about C++ separately. This will let you better understand what is essential and what is there because either cannot be done differently in C++ or because can be done much better in C++. I may cast downvotes but for learning concurrency as the beginner you will hardly find anything as handy as [Java Tutorial from Sun](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Even well known and respected Posix threads have been modeled after Solaris threads (which Sun has designed).